# how to set loopback.io prompt language to english

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I installed loopback using the npm install -g loopback-cli
When I execute lb commande, I get prompted in Spanish.
How can change the prompt language to english?

Answer (score 4):

You can use env property :

```
LANG=en lb ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're on Windows, but on Windows 7 this works: Go to Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Display Language -> Install/Uninstall Languages, and uninstall any non-English language.